# What is the correct way to apply `const` in Flutter?

Tags: performance, flutter, dart

I need to apply a radial gradient to my `Container()` widget. In the `BoxDecoration` I have applied the gradient the below manner.

**Case 1**

```
gradient: const RadialGradient(
   center: Alignment(0.0, -0.9),
   colors: [
       Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.19),
       Color.fromARGB(0, 209, 188, 254),
   ],
),
```

I got two more ideas to apply the `const` keyword which might slightly improve the performance. I'm confused about which approach makes sense.

**Case 2**

```
gradient: RadialGradient(
   center: const Alignment(0.0, -0.9),
   colors: [
       const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.19),
       const Color.fromARGB(0, 209, 188, 254),
   ],
),
```

**Case 3** - Adding const in all the places.

```
gradient: const RadialGradient(
   center: const Alignment(0.0, -0.9),
   colors: const [
       const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.19),
       const Color.fromARGB(0, 209, 188, 254),
   ],
),
```

In all the above 3 cases I want to understand which is the better approach. Also, applying `const` at the top level will do the work, i.e., sufficient for performance benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart's style guide explains how you should not do that: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-const-redundantly

If you just check out your linter it should've already told you to remove const from that widget.

Comment: For more details on when to use or not to use, the dart documentation is really clear and well written to find help on that matter.

Comment: I'm using the Android Studio, linter didn't give me hint. :/.

Comment: In this case, I assume the first case is correct then.

Comment: my understanding is that the performance gain from using the const keyword is related to how often that item is referred to by your program. If this is not a recurring Alignment or color scheme, it probably doesn't need to be const, but if it is, you should make them const and probably refactor them into named variables.